# Organize and relate class in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, organization, relation

Well, I am trying to adapt my old code to a more object oriented model but I find difficulties in doing it. The structure of my classes would look like this:

```
// config.php
class Config {
    const Setting1 = 'value';
    const Setting2 = 'value';
}

// main.php
include 'config.php'

class Main {
    var $Config;
    var $Info;
    var $Db;

    function _construct() {
        $this->Config = &new Config;
        $this->Info = &new Info;
        $this->Db = &new Db($this);
    }
}

class Info {
    function getSetting($a, $Config) {
        if ($a>0) return $Config::Setting1;
        return $Config::Setting2;
    }
}

class Db {
    function _construct($Main) {
        $Setting1 = $Main->Config::Setting1;
    }
}

// index.php
$Main = new Main;
echo $Main->Info->getSetting(1, $Main->Config);
```

So, as you see, there are incorrect things in this code. What I want is to have everything inside the `Main` class, create the `$Main` object and from there access any other object.
`Db` will need a constant from `Config` yet I don't want to create a new `Config` inside `Db` but use the one from `Main`. The same happens with Info.

Comment: which is the object you cannot access from main currently?

Comment: The problem lies at this code `$Setting1 = $Main->Config::Setting1`. I get a T_PAAMAYIM_NEKDOTAYIM error

Comment: What would be purpose of such design? Firstly, var's should be replaced by private, protected or public, Secondly you could write methods in main that would work with inner objects like write method getSetting($a) that would automatically pass Config to inner member so it would make Main class usage simplier to read

Comment: Also use public static instead of const

Comment: yes and you will not need an instance of Config. You can simply type Config::Setting1 where ever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be fixed with this:

```
// config.php
class Config {
    public static $Setting1 = 'value';
    public static $Setting2 = 'value';
}

// main.php
include('config.php');

class Main {
    private $Info = null;
    private $Db = null;

    public function _construct() {
        $this->Info = new Info();
        $this->Db = new Db();
    }

    public function getSetting($a) {
        return $this->Info->getSetting($a);
    }
}

class Info {
    public function getSetting($a) {
        if ($a>0) return Config::$Setting1;
        return Config::$Setting2;
    }
}

class Db {
    public function _construct() {
        $Setting1 = Config::$Setting1;
    }
}

// index.php
$Main = new Main();
echo $Main->getSetting(1);
```